# Generate custom marker (icon) out of two images in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, leaflet

In Javascript/CoffeeScript, using **Leaflet** to display a map, I would like to have custom markers out of a two custom images, and also featuring a shadow for the pin :

1. I want to have a "background" image with a color (or shape) to identify the category
2. On top, I want to have inside this image a specific image (logo) for each pin

I didn't find out how I could do that... Setting one image is quite easy but I don't know how to overlay them.

I could also consider using a tool to superpose/group/overlay these images (locally ?) before in order to send only one to the `Icon` Leaflet Class, but also there, I wouldn't know which tool to use.

Nevertheless, I still think that a double overlay would be more efficient and that my case could be useful for several people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I could finally fix it by myself. Here is the code, sorry it is CoffeeScript, but you may translate it to JavaScript using [this](http://js2coffee.org/#coffee2js).

The first thing I did was creating a new class for extending the DivIcon, to reactivate the shadow properties of DivIcon, which are deactivated by default :

```
class DivIconWithShadow extends L.DivIcon

  createShadow: (oldIcon) ->
    return L.Icon::createShadow.call this, oldIcon
```

Then in the code, I use the following to create the marker with the icon:

```
L.marker(latLng,
      icon: new DivIconWithShadow _.extend iconOptions,
          className: 'my-class',
          html: """
                <div class='icon_pin'>
                   <div class='logo' style='background-image: url(\"#{myVariablePath}\")'> </div>
                   <div class='top_pin'> </div>
                </div>
                """
    ).addTo(@map)
```

And then you may style it putting something like this in your CSS

```
.icon_pin {
  .top_pin {

    position: absolute;
    .at2x('../images/pingreen_open.png', 43px, 58px);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 43px;
    height: 58px;

  }

  .logo {
    position: absolute;
    width: 29px;
    height: 29px;
    margin-left: 7px;
    margin-top: 7px;
    background-size: 29px 29px;
    background-position: center center;
    background-color: white;

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Icon class has a shadowUrl property that you could use to set your background image.

Comment: your right gibbocool, actually I thought to update my question, because at the end, there are three images : the shadow and two icon images... So not enough or fitting for me. I should probably use some ImageMagick or so...